# Spring boot - hibernate Configuration issue(Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory')

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am configuring Hibernate in spring boot - getting below issue. I have added JAXB dependancy and checked so many fixes but it's not working for me.
Please help me to fix.

**Configuration**

Java version : Java 1.8

DB - MS sql server2012

Spring Boot : 2.1.0.RELEASE

**Error** :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/container/spi/BeanContainer
```

Application.java

```
package com.programmer.gate;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.programmer.gate.service.SoccerService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    SoccerService soccerService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        soccerService.addBarcelonaPlayer("Xavi Hernandez", "Midfielder", 6);

        List<String> players = soccerService.getAllTeamPlayers(1);
        for(String player : players)
        {
            System.out.println("Introducing Barca player => " + player);
        }
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
server.port=9093  
# create and drop tables and sequences, loads import.sql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-WIN10:1433;databaseName=employee
spring.datasource.username=emp_db_connect
spring.datasource.password=abi@123
spring.datasource.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver



# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
#logging.level.=debug
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.programmer.gate</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootHibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringBootHibernate</name>

  <properties>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

JAVA codes

```
package com.programmer.gate.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "player_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "player_Sequence", sequenceName = "PLAYER_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "num")
    private int num;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
    private Team team;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }


}
package com.programmer.gate.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "team_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "team_Sequence", sequenceName = "TEAM_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;

    public Team() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

}


package com.programmer.gate.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.programmer.gate.model.Player;

@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends CrudRepository<Player, Long> {

    List<Player> findByTeamId(long teamId);
}


package com.programmer.gate.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.programmer.gate.model.Team;

@Repository
public interface TeamRepository extends CrudRepository<Team, Long> {

    Team findByPlayers(long playerId);
}

package com.programmer.gate.service;

import java.util.List;

public interface SoccerService {
    public List<String> getAllTeamPlayers(long teamId);
    public void addBarcelonaPlayer(String name, String position, int number);
}


package com.programmer.gate.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.programmer.gate.model.Player;
import com.programmer.gate.model.Team;
import com.programmer.gate.repository.PlayerRepository;
import com.programmer.gate.repository.TeamRepository;

@Service
public class SoccerServiceImpl implements SoccerService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    public List<String> getAllTeamPlayers(long teamId) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Player> players = playerRepository.findByTeamId(teamId);
        for (Player player : players) {
            result.add(player.getName());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void addBarcelonaPlayer(String name, String position, int number) {
//      
        Team barcelona = teamRepository.findOne(1l);

        Player newPlayer = new Player();
        newPlayer.setName(name);
        newPlayer.setPosition(position);
        newPlayer.setNum(number);
        newPlayer.setTeam(barcelona);
        playerRepository.save(newPlayer);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've also had this exception before and was stuck for about a week. I think the exception could come up for a number of things, but in my case it was an issue with the naming of my db schema, the name of the db and what was stated in the spring-boot code didn't match up. So you could check that

Comment: @KesWalker I have checked - its configured correctly. checking some other scenarios too.